# If we know the operatornorm of a matrix A, what do we know about $Ax$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

We are given two matrices $M_1, M_2$ and two vectors $x,y$.

If we know that $||M_1||_2=||M_2||_2=1$ and $||x||_2^2\leq ||y||^2_2$, can we say something about
$||M_1x||_2^2$ vs. $||M_2 y||_2^2$?

So far, I got that $||M_1x||_2^2 \leq ||M_1||_2^2 ||x||^2_2 = ||x||_2^2 \leq ||y||_2^2$. But since $||y||^2_2 \geq ||M_2y||_2^2$ this does not really lead anywhere. I tried to find something about the relationship of $||M_2y||_2^2$ and $||y||_2^2$ that would allow me to uperbound $||y||_2^2$ in dependence of $||M_2y||^2_2$, but so far I have not found anything.

Does anybody see a way to obtain a result for $||M_1x||_2^2$, $||M_2y||_2^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M_2y=0$ and $y \neq 0$ then $x=ay$ satisfies the in equality $\|x\|_2^{2}\leq \|y\|_2^{2}$ for any small positive number $a$  but there is no reason why $M_1x=0$. So there is no inequality of the type $\|M_1x\|^{2}_2 \leq C\|M_2y\|^{2}_2$.